# Euler's Totient Function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement Euler's Totient Function (phi) in Javascript. So far this is what I have:

```js
function phi(n) {
  var result = n;
  for (let i=2; i*i<=n; i++) {
    if (n % i === 0) {
      while (n % i === 0) {
        n /= i;
        result -= result / i;
      }
    }
  }
  if (n > 1) {
    result -= result / n;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Unfortunately it all goes wrong when it comes up to multiples of 4. How do I improve this?

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/eulers-totient-function/

```js
function phi(n) {
  // return Greater Common Denominator of two given numbers
  function gcd(a, b) {
    if (a === 0) {
      return b;
    }

    return gcd(b % a, a);
  }

  // init
  var result = 1;

  // walk through all integers up to n
  for (let i = 2; i < n; i++) {
    if (gcd(i, n) === 1) {
      result++;
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I moved it here with `BigInt` implementation: https://github.com/gkucmierz/utils/blob/main/src/phi.mjs

Answer (score 0):

You should implement result = 1, then result ++ whenever you encounter a number coprime to the number you input. For that, you have to find the gcd function and that can be done with various methods, such as ArrayLists (like in Java) or with recursive functions.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most eficient way, but rather straightforward:

```
function phi(n) {
let divArr = []; // this is an array for the common divisors of our n
let primeCount = 0; // this is a counter of divisors

for (let i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++) {
    if (n % i === 0) {
        divArr.push(i);
    }
}


for (let j = n - 1; j > 0; j--) { //j is all potential coprimes
    for (let k = divArr.length - 1; k >= 0; k--) { //we get the indeces of the divArr and thus we can loop through all the potentail divisors

        //here we check if our potential coprimes are comprimes or not
        //run possible coprimes through the list of divisors        
        if (j % divArr[k] === 0 && divArr[k] !== 1) { //if a potential coprime can be divided by any element of the array of n's divisors we break the arra's loop i. e. k and go the j++
            break


        } else if (j % divArr[k] !== 0) { //if a potential coprime j cannot be divided by any element of divArray then it's ok and we simply stick to the next k and waiting for 2 possible cases: either it will reach 1 and we primeCount++ or eventually be divided and then we break the loop
            continue

        } else if (divArr[k] === 1) { //if can be divided without a remainder, greatest common divisor is not zero so we should break the loop
            primeCount++;
        }


    }
}
console.log(divArr, primeCount)
```

}